# How to do multidimentional time-series prediction in PyBrain?

Tags: python, time-series, prediction, pybrain

this is a repost from the PyBrain google group: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/pybrain/J9qv0nHuxVY.

I've been tinkering with OpenNN and FANN and have yet to find an ANN library that does what I need.

I'll break this up into short-term and medium-term goals, but first a little background...

### Background

I want to use an ANN to do time-series prediction of a 1000-2000 item vector varying over time. Each element is a Boolean value that represents the presence of a cluster of visual properties in a computer vision system at a particular moment in time.

The idea is to feed the network the vector at time t-1 with the vector at time t as a target value.

The output of the network will then be a prediction of what is expected to happen in the current time (t) based on the previous state (t-1) of the vector.

### Short Term

I would like to train an ANN so that it can learn to predict these vectors over time. That is, I would like to feed it an arbitrary vector and it return the vector that it has been trained to expect next. It's fine to use a finite dataSet for now, and I expect to start with normal epoch learning. I'm starting with a normal supervised data set where the input and targets are offset by one time unit. Thus far I have not been showing results as good as I was able to get in FANN in terms of MSE returns (no significant decrease of error after the first epoch), as described here: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/pybrain/QSfVHsFRXz0.

In FANN I was just using a simple MLP with 1026 inputs, 103 hidden, and 1026 outputs. Boolean inputs were scaled to -1 to 1 and weights were initialized to random values between -1 and 1. (This was done because apparently learning is faster with negative values than just 0-1). The network was reproducing input patterns quite well and ended up with a small MSE.

In PyBrain this is the current version of the code:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
# First try and using pyBrain for building an ANN. We'll start with an MLP for obvious reasons.

from pybrain.tools.shortcuts import buildNetwork
from pybrain.datasets import SupervisedDataSet
from pybrain.supervised.trainers import BackpropTrainer
from pybrain.tools.validation import ModuleValidator
import pickle, time

# Load the dataset (parse data)
print "Loading and parsing dataset..."
inputFile = open("../MLP/data/113584_backgroundState-filter-1.fann", 'r')
rawData = inputFile.readlines()
inputFile.close()
processedData = list()
for inputLine in rawData[1:]: # all but last element.
    data = inputLine.split() # Slicing to strip off the final newline
    scaleData = list()
    for item in data:
        scaleData.append(int(item))
    processedData.append(scaleData)

# Create dataset from parsed data
inputData = SupervisedDataSet(1027, 1027)
for index in xrange(0,len(processedData)-1,2): # every second line.
    inputData.addSample(processedData[index], processedData[index+1])

del processedData # no longer needed

# Build the same network as in FANN
net = buildNetwork(1027, 103, 1027, bias=True)

# Train the network
print "Training network..."
trainer = BackpropTrainer(net, inputData, verbose = True)
for i in xrange(5):
    startTime = time.time()
    error = trainer.train()
    print "ERROR " + str(i) + " " + str(error) # test network (calculate error)
    print "ProcessingTime " + str(i) + " " + str(time.time() - startTime)

# save results.
print "Saving network..."
fileObject = open('network.pybrain', 'w')
pickle.dump(net, fileObject)

# For each input pattern, what is the output?
# Compatible with FANN output
print "Testing network and generating results..."
i = 0;
for inputPattern in inputData['input']:
    outputPattern = net.activate(inputPattern)
    for j in xrange(len(inputPattern)):
        print "RESULT " + str(i) + " " + str(j) + " " + str(inputPattern[j]) + " " + str(outputPattern[j])
    i += 1

print "Done."
```

Any recommendations for how to best set this up for learning? (I expect I'll need recurrency, but wanted to compare PyBrain to my previous FANN results with a plain MLP.)

I actually tried building this network with recurrent=True, but in all my tests python ended up using all the available RAM and crashed (there is 8GB ram on this machine). I'm not sure how I can enable recurrency without a huge increase of memory footprint.

### Medium Term

Eventually, the system will have to be running on-line where inputs are fed on the fly and constantly changing. This means epoch training will not be possible, so I need to be able to run a single iteration of the learning algorithm. I realize it will be hard for the ANN to learn, but the good news is there will be no shortage of data-points (at least 100,000s). Because there is no fixed set of data, there is no need for convergence. I expect error will rise and fall as new or stable patterns are presented.

Thanks for any comments and suggestions.